# Rails 3.2 ActionMailer not rendering html in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, mailchimp

I have a production machine that is your basic CentOS machine on Amazon AWS, nothing special there.

I am essentially running this:

```
@digest = WeeklyDigest.most_recent.first
@mailer = DigestMailer.weekly_digest(@digest)
@mailchimp = MailChimp.new
@mailchimp.new_digest(@mailer.body.to_s)
```

What this code does is finds my latest weekly_digest, generate a new mailer using that, and then I grab the html from that and send it to mailchimp.

I have a weekly_digest.html.slim in app/views/digest_mailer and I have a digest_mailer.html.slim in app/views/layouts.

All of this works fine on development. @mailer returns this:

```
#<Mail::Message:70180219750380, Multipart: false, Headers: <From: no-reply@example.com>, <To: fake@fake.com>, <Subject: Weekly Digest>, <Mime-Version: 1.0>, <Content-Type: text/html>>
```

When I run the exact same code on my AWS machine it returns:

```
#<Mail::Message:158221880, Multipart: false, Headers: <From: no-reply@example.com>, <To: fake@fake.com>, <Subject: Weekly Digest>, <Mime-Version: 1.0>, <Content-Type: text/plain>>
```

The content type on dev is html and its text/plain on prod.

Any ideas about why this might happen? Something in the environment settings? I'm not finding much helpful in the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be a discrepancy in default_content_type between your environment configurations.  Try adding:

```
config.action_mailer.default_content_type = 'text/html'
```

To either your `production.rb` config file, or optionally your `application.rb` config file.

You should also check if a text template exists at `app/views/digest_mailer/weekly_digest.text.erb` and remove it since you're only trying to send HTML emails anyway.

Longterm you should consider sending multipart emails with both text and HTML.  The **[Premailer Gem](https://github.com/alexdunae/premailer)** makes it really easy by automatically generating the text-part from the HTML template.  That way you don't have to maintain both a text and HTML template and keep them in sync.

Comment: I added ActionMailer::Base.default :content_type => "text/html" to the environment.rb file, however, the .body of the mailer is returning ''. That's sort of a different question but do you have any idea why that might be? it returns a whole html document on development. Could it be due to my using of slim instead of erb?

Comment: It's hard to say for sure.  The way you're using Mailchimp is a little different than the typical way mail is sent in Rails, which makes it a little harder to debug.  I would suggest doing a test sending email from your CentOS server with a basic Gmail account and `DigestMailer.weekly_digest(@digest).deliver` to trigger the send.  If that works you know the issue is with the Mailchimp sending strategy.  If not it's something with your template.  Either way it will tell you which part of things you need to dig into.

Comment: well i don't have any stmp settings, but when i .deliver it seems to "Deliver" no problem. Hmmmmmmm. How annoying.